# Applying a kernel with OpenCV in C++

Tags: c++, opencv

If I apply a Sobel filter to an image in Python using `scipy.ndimage.filters.convole` I get meaningful results, for example, for this simple input image `img`

```
0 255 0
0 255 0
0 255 0
```

the convolution

```
dimage.filters.convolve(img, Kx)
```

with `Kx`

```
-1 0 1
-2 0 2
-1 0 1
```

returns a meaningful gradient in x-direction:

```
-1020 0 1020
-1020 0 1020
-1020 0 1020
```

I don't know how to get a equivalent result using openCV2 in C++ though. When I define the input image by

```
int image_data[9] = {0, 255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 255, 0};
cv::Mat image = cv::Mat(3, 3, CV_32F, image_data);
```

and apply the kernel by

```
cv::Mat gradientx; 
double sobelx_data[9] = {-1, 0, 1, -2, 0, 2, -1, 0, 1};
cv::Mat sobelx = cv::Mat(3, 3, CV_32F, sobelx_data);
cv::filter2D(image, gradientx, -1, sobelx);
```

I get the following result from

```
for(int row=0; row<gradientx.rows; row++) {
  for(int col=0; col<gradientx.cols; col++) {
  std::cout << gradientx.at<int>(row,col) << std::endl;
  }
}
```

it returns the following image

```
478 -2147482660 478
478 -2147482660 478
478 -2147482660 478
```

There seems to be an overflow problem, but I don't know why. Trying to get values from `gradientx.at<double>(row,col)` produces

```
-1.68911e-311 8.10602e-312 8.11663e-312
-1.68911e-311 8.10602e-312 8.11663e-312
-1.68911e-311 2.122e-314 8.54412e-72
```

Can someone tell me why this is? Isn't `filter2D` supposed to do a 2D convolution on the image, and why do I get weird values when addressing the output pixels with `<double>`? Thank you.

Comment: `CV_32F` is a `float`.

Comment: @beaker Thank you, I changed it to float.. Put now it prints me the zero-matrix...

Comment: Now it looks like you're running into problems with the border type. I'll post an answer in a sec.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, here's your code with the types corrected (I've also added more parameters to `filter2D`):

```
float image_data[9] = {0, 255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 255, 0};
cv::Mat image = cv::Mat(3, 3, CV_32F, image_data);
std::cout << "image = " << std::endl << image << std::endl;

cv::Mat gradientx;
float sobelx_data[9] = {-1, 0, 1, -2, 0, 2, -1, 0, 1};
cv::Mat sobelx = cv::Mat(3, 3, CV_32F, sobelx_data);
std::cout << "sobelx = " << std::endl << sobelx << std::endl;

cv::filter2D(image, gradientx, -1, sobelx, cv::Point(-1, -1), 0,
             cv::BORDER_DEFAULT);
std::cout << "gradientx = " << std::endl << gradientx << std::endl;
```

The result is:

```
image = 
[0, 255, 0;
 0, 255, 0;
 0, 255, 0]
sobelx = 
[-1, 0, 1;
 -2, 0, 2;
 -1, 0, 1]
gradientx = 
[0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0]
```

If you look at the top of the documentation page on [filtering](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html), you'll see all of the border types that OpenCV uses. By default, `filter2D` uses `BORDER_REFLECT_101`. This is probably not what we want, so let's change it to `BORDER_REPLICATE`.

```
cv::filter2D(image, gradientx, -1, sobelx, cv::Point(-1, -1), 0,
             cv::BORDER_REPLICATE);
```

Result:

```
image = 
[0, 255, 0;
 0, 255, 0;
 0, 255, 0]
sobelx = 
[-1, 0, 1;
 -2, 0, 2;
 -1, 0, 1]
gradientx = 
[1020, 0, -1020;
 1020, 0, -1020;
 1020, 0, -1020]
```

That's better, but the values are flipped. If you look at the bottom of the function description for [`filter2D`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#filter2d) you'll see that it actually computes the cross correlation rather than the convolution. So we need to flip the kernel to get the correct results.

```
cv::Mat sobelxflip;
cv::flip(sobelx, sobelxflip, -1);

cv::filter2D(image, gradientx, -1, sobelxflip, cv::Point(-1, -1), 0,
             cv::BORDER_REPLICATE);
std::cout << "gradientx = " << std::endl << gradientx << std::endl;
```

Result:

```
gradientx = 
[-1020, 0, 1020;
 -1020, 0, 1020;
 -1020, 0, 1020]
```